# Errors reloading SciPy

Tags: python, scipy, reload, anaconda

Running `my_script.py` below returns an error in the reloading process, with the final error being:

```
ImportError: No module named moves
```

which seems to be triggered by this statement

```
from scipy.lib.six.moves import xrange
```

in the file `scipy/stats/stats.pyc`. Could this be a bug? Os is there a problem with my installation?

**my_script.py:**

```
import my_package.my_module as my_module
reload(my_module)
```

**my_module.py:**

```
from scipy.stats import gaussian_kde
```

and below is the full error trace:

```
Reloading dx_stats.scipy
Reloading scipy
Reloading __future__
Reloading numpy
Reloading numpy.__config__
Reloading numpy.version
Reloading numpy._import_tools
Reloading os
Reloading errno
Reloading posix
Reloading posixpath
Reloading stat
Reloading genericpath
Reloading warnings
Reloading linecache
Reloading types
Reloading _warnings
Reloading UserDict
Reloading _abcoll
Reloading abc
Reloading _weakrefset
Reloading _weakref
Reloading copy_reg
Reloading numpy.testing
Reloading unittest
Reloading unittest.result
Reloading unittest.os
Reloading unittest.sys
Reloading unittest.traceback
Reloading traceback
Reloading unittest.StringIO
Reloading StringIO
Reloading unittest.functools
Reloading functools
Reloading _functools
Reloading unittest.case
Reloading unittest.collections
Reloading collections
Reloading _collections
Reloading operator
Reloading keyword
Reloading heapq
Reloading itertools
Reloading _heapq
Reloading thread
Reloading unittest.difflib
Reloading difflib
Reloading re
Reloading sre_compile
Reloading _sre
Reloading sre_parse
Reloading sre_constants
Reloading unittest.pprint
Reloading pprint
Reloading cStringIO
Reloading unittest.re
Reloading unittest.types
Reloading unittest.warnings
Reloading unittest.util
Reloading unittest.suite
Reloading unittest.loader
Reloading unittest.fnmatch
Reloading fnmatch
Reloading unittest.main
Reloading unittest.signals
Reloading unittest.signal
Reloading signal
Reloading unittest.weakref
Reloading weakref
Reloading exceptions
Reloading unittest.runner
Reloading unittest.time
Reloading time
Reloading numpy.testing.utils
Reloading numpy.testing.nosetester
Reloading numpy.compat
Reloading numpy.compat._inspect
Reloading numpy.compat.py3k
Reloading numpy.core
Reloading numpy.core.info
Reloading numpy.core.numeric
Reloading numpy.core.umath
Reloading numpy.core.numerictypes
Reloading numpy.core.multiarray
Reloading cPickle
Reloading numpy.core._dotblas
Reloading numpy.core.arrayprint
Reloading numpy.core.fromnumeric
Reloading numpy.core.records
Reloading numpy.core.defchararray
Reloading numpy.core.memmap
Reloading numpy.core.function_base
Reloading numpy.core.machar
Reloading numpy.core.getlimits
Reloading numpy.core.shape_base
Reloading numpy.testing.numpytest
Reloading numpy.lib
Reloading math
Reloading numpy.lib.info
Reloading numpy.lib.type_check
Reloading numpy.lib.ufunclike
Reloading numpy.lib.index_tricks
Reloading numpy.matrixlib
Reloading numpy.matrixlib.defmatrix
Reloading numpy.lib.function_base
Reloading numpy.lib.twodim_base
Reloading numpy.lib._compiled_base
Reloading numpy.lib.utils
Reloading numpy.lib.stride_tricks
Reloading numpy.lib.nanfunctions
Reloading numpy.lib.shape_base
Reloading numpy.lib.polynomial
Reloading numpy.linalg
Reloading numpy.linalg.info
Reloading numpy.linalg.linalg
Reloading numpy.lib.arraysetops
Reloading numpy.lib.npyio
Reloading numpy.lib._datasource
Reloading shutil
Reloading pwd
Reloading grp
Reloading numpy.lib._iotools
Reloading future_builtins
Reloading numpy.lib.financial
Reloading numpy.lib.arrayterator
Reloading numpy.lib.arraypad
Reloading numpy.random
Reloading numpy.random.info
Reloading numpy.random.mtrand
Reloading numpy.fft
Reloading numpy.fft.info
Reloading numpy.fft.fftpack
Reloading numpy.fft.helper
Reloading numpy.lib.scimath
Reloading scipy.__config__
Reloading scipy.version
Reloading scipy.stats
Reloading scipy.stats.stats
Reloading scipy.lib
Reloading scipy.lib.six
Reloading scipy.lib.operator
Reloading scipy.lib.sys
Reloading scipy.lib.types
Reloading scipy.lib.StringIO
Reloading scipy.lib.six.moves

---------------------------------------------------------------------------
ImportError                               Traceback (most recent call last)
<ipython-input-1-5f8b4764607d> in <module>()

/Users/josh/anaconda/envs/py27/lib/python2.7/site-packages/IPython/lib/deepreload.pyc in reload(module, exclude)
    329     try:
    330         with replace_import_hook(deep_import_hook):
--> 331             ret = deep_reload_hook(module)
    332     finally:
    333         found_now = {}

/Users/josh/anaconda/envs/py27/lib/python2.7/site-packages/IPython/lib/deepreload.pyc in deep_reload_hook(m)
    299 
    300     try:
--> 301         newm = imp.load_module(name, fp, filename, stuff)
    302     except:
    303          # load_module probably removed name from modules because of

/Users/josh/code/reps/sandbox/utils/py_packages/team/pdf_histograms.pyc in <module>()
      2 # import matplotlib.pyplot as plt
      3 import scipy
----> 4 from scipy.stats import gaussian_kde
      5 
      6 # # from avr_utils.debugging import *

/Users/josh/anaconda/envs/py27/lib/python2.7/site-packages/IPython/lib/deepreload.pyc in deep_import_hook(name, globals, locals, fromlist, level)
    244     tail = head
    245     while name:
--> 246         tail, name, buf = load_next(tail, tail, name, buf)
    247 
    248     # If tail is None, both get_parent and load_next found

/Users/josh/anaconda/envs/py27/lib/python2.7/site-packages/IPython/lib/deepreload.pyc in load_next(mod, altmod, name, buf)
    144     buf += subname
    145 
--> 146     result = import_submodule(mod, subname, buf)
    147     if result is None and mod != altmod:
    148         result = import_submodule(altmod, subname, subname)

/Users/josh/anaconda/envs/py27/lib/python2.7/site-packages/IPython/lib/deepreload.pyc in import_submodule(mod, subname, fullname)
    189 
    190         try:
--> 191             m = imp.load_module(fullname, fp, filename, stuff)
    192         except:
    193             # load_module probably removed name from modules because of

/Users/josh/anaconda/envs/py27/lib/python2.7/site-packages/scipy/stats/__init__.pyc in <module>()
    322 from __future__ import division, print_function, absolute_import
    323 
--> 324 from .stats import *
    325 from .distributions import *
    326 from .rv import *

/Users/josh/anaconda/envs/py27/lib/python2.7/site-packages/IPython/lib/deepreload.pyc in deep_import_hook(name, globals, locals, fromlist, level)
    240     parent, buf = get_parent(globals, level)
    241 
--> 242     head, name, buf = load_next(parent, None if level < 0 else parent, name, buf)
    243 
    244     tail = head

/Users/josh/anaconda/envs/py27/lib/python2.7/site-packages/IPython/lib/deepreload.pyc in load_next(mod, altmod, name, buf)
    144     buf += subname
    145 
--> 146     result = import_submodule(mod, subname, buf)
    147     if result is None and mod != altmod:
    148         result = import_submodule(altmod, subname, subname)

/Users/josh/anaconda/envs/py27/lib/python2.7/site-packages/IPython/lib/deepreload.pyc in import_submodule(mod, subname, fullname)
    189 
    190         try:
--> 191             m = imp.load_module(fullname, fp, filename, stuff)
    192         except:
    193             # load_module probably removed name from modules because of

/Users/josh/anaconda/envs/py27/lib/python2.7/site-packages/scipy/stats/stats.pyc in <module>()
    232 import math
    233 
--> 234 from scipy.lib.six.moves import xrange
    235 
    236 # friedmanchisquare patch uses python sum

/Users/josh/anaconda/envs/py27/lib/python2.7/site-packages/IPython/lib/deepreload.pyc in deep_import_hook(name, globals, locals, fromlist, level)
    244     tail = head
    245     while name:
--> 246         tail, name, buf = load_next(tail, tail, name, buf)
    247 
    248     # If tail is None, both get_parent and load_next found

/Users/josh/anaconda/envs/py27/lib/python2.7/site-packages/IPython/lib/deepreload.pyc in load_next(mod, altmod, name, buf)
    151 
    152     if result is None:
--> 153         raise ImportError("No module named %.200s" % name)
    154 
    155     return result, next, buf

ImportError: No module named moves
```

I am using

```
> python --version
Python 2.7.6 :: Anaconda 1.8.0 (x86_64)
```

Below is my `pip freeze`:

```
$ pip freeze
Cython==0.19.2
Flask==0.10.1
Jinja2==2.7.1
MDP==3.3
MarkupSafe==0.18
PIL==1.1.7
PyAudio==0.2.7
PySAL==1.6.0
PyYAML==3.10
Pygments==1.6
SQLAlchemy==0.8.3
Sphinx==1.1.3
Theano==0.6.0
VTK==5.10.1
Werkzeug==0.9.4
appnope==0.0.6-dev
apptools==4.2.0
astropy==0.2.5
atom==0.3.4
beautifulsoup4==4.3.1
binstar==0.3.0
biopython==1.62
bitarray==0.8.1
blaze==0.2dev
bokeh==unknown
boto==2.15.0
casuarius==1.1
chaco==4.3.0
colorama==0.2.7
configobj==4.7.2
cubes==0.10.2
cvxopt==1.1.6
distribute==0.6.45
docutils==0.11
enable==4.3.0
enaml==0.8.3
envisage==4.3.0
epc==0.0.5
gevent==0.13.8
gevent-websocket==0.3.6
gevent-zeromq==0.2.2
greenlet==0.4.1
grin==1.2.1
h5py==2.2.0
ipython==1.2.1
itsdangerous==0.23
jedi==0.7.0
keyring==3.2
llvmmath==0.1
llvmpy==0.12.0
lxml==3.2.3
matplotlib==1.3.1
mayavi==4.3.0
memory-profiler==0.31
meta==development
netCDF4==1.0.6
networkx==1.8.1
nltk==2.0.4
nose==1.3.0
numba==0.11.0
numexpr==2.3.1
numpy==1.8.0
openpyxl==1.6.2
pandas==0.13.1
patsy==0.2.1
pep8==1.4.6
ply==3.4
praw==2.1.12
psutil==1.1.2
psycopg2==2.5.1
py==1.4.17
py4j==0.8.1
pycosat==0.6.0
pycparser==2.09.1
pycrypto==2.6.1
pycurl==7.19.0
pyface==4.3.0
pyflakes==0.7.3
pykit==0.1
pymc==2.3
pyparsing==1.5.6
pysam==0.6
pytest==2.4.2
python-cjson==1.0.5
python-dateutil==1.5
pytz==2013b
pyzmq==2.2.0.1
qds-sdk==1.0.10-beta
redis==2.7.2
requests==1.2.3
rope==0.9.4
scikit-image==0.9.3
scikit-learn==0.14.1
scipy==0.13.3
sexpdata==0.0.3
six==1.5.2
spyder==2.2.5
statsmodels==0.5.0
sympy==0.7.4.1
tables==3.0.0
tornado==3.1.1
traits==4.3.0
traitsui==4.3.0
update-checker==0.8
wsgiref==0.1.2
xlrd==0.9.2
xlwt==0.7.5
```

Comment: Side note: `import my_package.my_module as my_module` is usually written more simply as `from my_package import my_module`.

Answer (score 1):

Your version of SciPy (0.13.3) does some "magic" with `xrange` and `scipy.lib.six.moves` (https://github.com/scipy/scipy/blob/maintenance/0.13.x/scipy/lib/six.py#L188). In fact, `scipy.lib.six.moves` is not stored in a `scipy/lib/six/` source directory but is added to the known modules in the memory of the Python interpreter, so strange interactions might occur.

What about *not* reloading `my_module`, in your code? this may explain your problem.

I have SciPy 0.14 and I do not observe any problem with your code, so upgrading might also solve the problem.

Answer (score 0):

Ubuntu? Try this:

> sudo apt-get install python-six

If this didn't work, you can try to compile Scipy from source(the latest source on github didn't solve my problem, maybe you can try 0.13.3, download from http://mail.scipy.org/pipermail/scipy-user/2014-February/035419.html)

How I solve this:

- install from building the latest source
- update python-six